# ReactJS Redux Loading Image Dynamically from Variable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, message, boilerplate

I am currently working on a React + Redux Project and wanted to use language messages to render an image.

The problem is that, because the image name is dynamic (because of the language switching), I can't use `require(imageVar)` to load the image.

What I currently am working with is this (this is inside of the render() function):

```
FormattedMessage {...messages.fullLogo}>
        {
          (fullLogo) => <Img src={require(`${fullLogo}`)} alt="Banner" />
        }
</FormattedMessage>
```

This should theoretically load the image from the url (yes `fullLogo` is a full url to the image).

What I tried inside of src={} was:

```
require(`${fullLogo}`)
require(fullLogo)
require("" + fullLogo)
require(String(fullLogo))
require(fullLogo.toString())
```

Everytime I try one of these (except the 3rd one - gives me an fatal error) I get an `"Could not Load Module './img/image.png'"` error.

I guess this means, that the name does load but require somehow cannot access the variable.

However if i put the path directly into the `require()` function. It successfully loads the image.

I don't want this though. I want it to load it dynamically.

Maybe you guys have some experience with it.

Thanks in advance!

PS: If you need any extra code, let me know!

Comment: You don't need to use require.

Comment: @George then what should i use?

Comment: Just put the url in src. Require is used if you are storing the image locally.

Comment: src expacts just a url, if you write a `react-native` project then you need to use require.

Comment: @George I have it locally. may have been a misunderstanding. And I have to have it locally

Comment: @cowCrazy ok but how do i use require? In this case

Answer (score 0):

[You can't dynamically require files by variable at runtime](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391), since `require` happens before runtime, when you bundle your app together (e.g. using webpack).

> Based on how the packager works, this isn't really possible with require.
>   Packaging happens once before runtime so those variables don't have values yet.

What do you mean by langage switching ? What does `message.fullLogo` contains ? If it contains an url, just use that url without require:

Comment: Using url instead of require also needs the images to be moved to the public folder rather than the source folder, which probably requires a little bit of whichever builder OP uses configuration.